# Unity3D There should be '<AppName>_Data' folder next to the executable

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, directory

as the title says, I'm having a problem with using my .exe-File.
I'm building a Unity3D project with default Build and Player Settings.
The final build consist of the following: MyProject.exe and MyProject_Data (Folder). The .exe is located in the same folder with MyProject_Data. Still I'm getting the following error:

"There should be 'MyProject_Data'
folder next to the executable"

So far I've tried installing it in different folders (e.g. desktop, inside the Unity Project folder...).
I still ended up with the same problem.

Other projects are building fine and I'm having no problems opening their .exe-Files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem by doing this:

Player Settings > Optimization > Api Compability Level > .NET 2.0

was .Net 2.0 Subset before.

I hope this is not a bad workaround that will lead to different problems in the long run!

Comment: Weird that you got that error and this fixed it. By the way, you can safely rename the folder to just 'Data' which looks nicer (of course, compiling again won't recognize it, but it works for deployment). Feel free to mark your own answer as accepted!